# Rangefilt implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am given an assignment to implement Range filter. Here is my code for that:

```
I=imread('cameraman.tif');
I=im2double(I);
mkdir('./output_images/');
%Salt and pepper
SP= imnoise(I,'salt & pepper',0.004);
stemName='Salt&pepper';
OutputFileName = ['./output_images/' stemName '_noise.tif'];
imwrite( SP,OutputFileName);  
[row col]=size(SP);
%SP=padarray(SP,[3 2],'replicate','both');
for i=2:row-1
    for j=2:col-1
        neigbours=[0 0 0; 0 0 0;0 0 0];
        neibours(1,1)=SP(i-1,j-1);
        neibours(1,2)=SP(i-1,j);
        neibours(1,3)=SP(i-1,j+1);
        neibours(2,1)=SP(i,j-1);
        neibours(2,3)=SP(i,j+1);
        neibours(3,1)=SP(i+1,j-1);
        neibours(3,2)=SP(i+1,j);
        neibours(3,3)=SP(i+1,j+1);
        neibours(2,2)=SP(i,j);
        maxi= max(neibours(:));
        mini= min(neibours(:));
        newvalue= maxi-mini;
        SP(i,j)=newvalue;
    end
end
OutputFileName = ['./output_images/' stemName '_filtered.tif'];
imwrite( SP,OutputFileName);
```

Noise is applied to image I and then saved to SP. A new array is created neibours in which all the neighbors including current pixel is added. Then the difference between max and min is calculated and stored to current pixel. Problem is that when I compare the image generated from this code and the one generated from builtin function rangefilt() results are different.

Comment: Closing due to simple typo. You were overwriting the input values of your matrix with those of your output values.

Answer (score 0):

I was updating same matrix SP. When I created a new matrix S and stored values in that one, it produced the same results as that of built in one.